# Understanding Real analyticity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, analyticity

I'm going to state my assumption of the definition of Real analyticity, and how I understand it based on my current understanding. Please tell me if they are correct or not and please help me perfecting them:

***Definition:***

$f$ is Real analytic at $x = c$, if f is equal to its Taylor Series not only at $x = c$ but also for all $x$ within the neighborhood of $x = c$ (neighborhood means the open interval with $x = c$ as center). In other words, $f$ is Real analytic at $x = c$ if $f$ is equal to its Taylor Series $\forall x \in (c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon): \epsilon > 0$ , therefore Taylor Series is:

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!} (x-c)^n$$

***My understanding of analyticity:***

1/ It’s possible that Taylor Series doesn’t converge to $f$ for all $x$ within Interval of Convergence. Therefore, assume $x = c$ is being checked for analyticity, and $(c−R,c+R)$ is Interval of Convergence (R is Radius of Convergence). Then $(c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon) \subseteq (c - R, c + R)$

2/ $f$ only needs to be infinitely differentiable within $(c−R,c+R)$

3/ For any $x$ being checked of analyticity, Taylor Series has to be around that $x$, it means that the $x$ becomes a center of both the Taylor Series and the Interval of Convergence. For example, if $x = j$ is being checked of analyticity then Taylor Series would be ...

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(j)}{n!} (x-j)^n$$

... , Interval of Convergence would then be $(j−R,j+R)$ and the interval where Taylor Series converges to $f$ is $(j - \epsilon, j + \epsilon)$, consequently $(j - \epsilon, j + \epsilon) \subseteq (j−R,j+R)$.

4/ There are 3 intervals, the largest interval being $(c−R,c+R)$ which is Interval of Convergence. The interval where Taylor Series converges to f $(c−M,c+M):M > 0$ . And the smallest one being $(c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon)$ . So, $(c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon) \subseteq (c−M,c+M) \subseteq (c−R,c+R)$

*All what I wrote above are assumptions, nothing is confirmed, please help me fix them if they are false. Any help is appreciated.*

Edit: Added the 4th point.

Comment: almost everything looks correct with the only caveat being that $\epsilon$ above may depend on $x$ (actually there is a nontrivial beautiful theorem that says that if an infinitely differentiable function has a Taylor series with a radius of convergence that is bounded below on some interval, it is analytic there - in other words, if $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!} (x-c)^n$ converges for $|x-c| \ge \delta >0$ for all $c \in I$ then it must converge to $f$ at least on a smaller interval around each $c$

Comment: @BS the result I was mentioning states that if at each point $x$ of an interval the Taylor series associated to an infinitely differentiable function has radius of convergence $r_x \ge \delta>0$ then the function is analytic there; it is of course easy to construct a function that is not analytic but whose series converges everywhere at a point, however at neighboring points the radius of convergence of the associated Taylor series will go to zero as we approach this singular point

Comment: More generally for smooth functions with Taylor series that converge at each point of an interval ( meaning again that for each $c$ the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $c$ has non zero radius of convergence) the points of non analyticity (so the $c$'s where the corresponding Taylor series centered at $c$ doesn't converge to the function on a small interval) are rare as they form a closed nowhere dense set

Comment: @Conrad Thank you so much! I'm studying everything you said as they are very complicated. Can you please tell me what you think of my 4th point of "my understanding of analyticity" which I've just added?

Comment: Regarding point 4, i would say that in many ways what is important is the existence of $\epsilon$ (given of course that $R>0$) so the Taylor series converges to $f$ on $|x-c| < \epsilon$ so the function is analytic; $M$ is usually less important in itself (unless $f$ has a nice formula or such) as $f$ can be patched together in various ways so $M$ may reflect this rather than anything interesting about $f$ - that in the case that $f$ infinitely differentiable but with singularities;

Comment: if $f$ is real analytic on the full interval, then still $M$ may reflect complex extension behavior (see $1/(1+x^2)$ which is real analytic on the full real line but its Taylor series at any point converges only on finite intervals reflecting the complex singularities at $\pm i$) - eg at $0$ the radius of convergence is $1$ while at $5$ the radius of convergence is $\sqrt {26}$ since the distance from $5$ to either singularity is that

Comment: @Conrad Really appreciate your help, kind sir.

Comment: @Conrad Hi! I've just discovered something. At $x = c$, function "$f(c)$" is already equal to Taylor Series "$T(c)$" because it’s the center of Taylor Series, so when I said: “***To check if f is analytic at $x = c$, Taylor Series must be centered at $x = c$***” - That’s wrong, right? Because obviously when *Taylor Series centered at $x = c$* is formed, $f(c)$ is automatically equal to $T(c)$, then why do we even need to check analyticity at $x = c$? If you agree with this point, then can you please help me when I create a new question that's also about the definition of analyticity? Thank you

Comment: Analyticity at $c$ means the Taylor series centered at $c$ converges on some small interval centered at $c$ to the function

Comment: @Conrad Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me expand the comments above as real analyticity is a tricky concept; so consider $f$ an infinitely differentiable real function on some real interval $I$; for each $c \in I$ we can associate to $f$ its Taylor series centered there (here we consider only the case $c$ interior to $I$ as the case where $c$ is an end point is similar with the necessary changes to one-sideness):

$$T_c(x)=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!} (x-c)^n$$

Let $r_c$ the radius of convergence of $T_c$; there are three possibilities:

1: $r_c=0$ so the Taylor series is called divergent (it converges only at $c$ but not on any open neighborhood)

2: $r_c >0$ (including $r_c=\infty$) but there is no small open neighborhood of $c$ for which $T_c(x)=f(x)$ (here the usual bump function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}, x \ne 0, f(0)=0$ comes to mind as its Taylor series $T_0$ at zero is zero so has infinite radius of convergence but  $T_c(x) \ne f(x)$ for $x \ne 0$

3: $r_c >0$ and there is an $0<\epsilon_c \le r_c$ st $T_c(x)=f(x), |x-c|< \epsilon_c$ (while also we assume $|x-c| < \epsilon_c \subset I$); then $f$ is called real analytic at $c$ and by the usual theory of power series it follows that $f$ is real analytic on $(c-\epsilon_c, c+\epsilon_c)$ so $T_y(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ on a small interval around $y$ for any $y \in (c-\epsilon_c, c+\epsilon_c)$ and moreover we are guaranteed such convergence on any interval centered at $y$ and of radius at most $\epsilon_c-|c-y|$

Note that in case 3, it can happen that $\epsilon_c<r_c$ (take now the one sided bump $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}, x >0, f(x)=0, x \le 0$ and note that for every $c<0$ the radius of $T_c$ is infinite but $T_c$ converges to $f$ only on $(-\infty,0]$ so $\epsilon_c=|c|$)

By the above real analyticity is an open and local property (so the points $c$ where $f$ is analytic form a (relatively) open subset of $I$ and analyticity depends only on the values of $f$ in a small neighborhood of $c$)

There are at least two important results due to [Boas](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-41/issue-4/A-theorem-on-analytic-functions-of-a-real-variable/bams/1183498133.full) that should be known (and are not that hard to prove, see linked reference).

Assume $f$ infinitely differentiable on $I$ st $r_c>0$ for all $c \in I$ (so we are only in cases 2,3); then the set of points $E$ where $f$ is not real analytic is closed and nowhere dense.

If in addition there is $\delta>0$ st $r_c \ge \delta>0$ for all $c \in I$ then $E$ is empty and $f$ is real analytic on $I$

Comment: Nicely explained.